# Extract project and Report level metadata from obiee12c

Tags: weblogic12c, obiee

As we have below command to extract all the projects/reports from obiee12c analytics

```
exportServiceInstance( '/oraclehome/user_projects/domains/bi','mycompany.facility', '/workDir', '/scratch/exportDir')
```

This command provided extracts all metadata information of every projects and folders and report present in analytics as a archived bar file.Is there any other way were I can get metadata information of particular report or project which I need and not all the projects as a bar file or any?

Answer (score 0):

OBIEE comes with several client tool with the "Catalog Manager" being the admin tool of choice for handling catalog-related tasks like yours. It exists as a GU and a command line both so you can also automate/script repetitive tasks like reporting on your reporting objects.

Have a look at the official documentation as it's too much text to just post into an answer here and you may come across things you want or need in there which go beyond your initial question here:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIESG/GUID-E804B1AF-B792-4929-BE47-33CA0F668715.htm#BIESG340

Comment: can you provide me a link where it shows how can we extract metadata for particular report?

Comment: You open catalog manager, navigate to the folder your object in question is in and run the report just for that folder. It's extremely simple. Just use Catalog Manager once yourself and it will visible immediately.

Comment: not able to figure out how to run the report from catalog manager

Comment: I can just see the metadata of it in properties->editxml tab but not able to export it to a bar file or a .xml file in local machine

Comment: I tried archive option but the file contents are encoded  and the format is file type.How can I extract those?

Answer (score 0):

- I you only need the reports you can export your reports folder directly from the catalog in OBI web interface or using "Catalog Manager" as suggested by @Chris.
- For the repository you can connect Online to your server then from file -> Copy As

Note : exporting the service instance is used for environment migration, it's easier to move all what you need with one bar file (for example having DEV PROD environments).

Comment: I can just see the metadata of it in properties->editxml tab in catalog manager but not able to export it to a bar file or a .xml file in local machine

Comment: where can I find this option.Could not find in CatalogManager ```For the repository you can connect Online to your server then from file -> Copy As```